# Parse XML in Python with encoding other than utf-8

Tags: python, xml, character-encoding

Any clue on how to parse xml in python that has: encoding='Windows-1255' in it?
At least the lxml.etree parser won't even look at the string when there's an "encoding" tag in the XML header which isn't "utf-8" or "ASCII".

Running the following code fails with:

**ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without
 declaration.**

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8')

def convert_xml_to_utf8(xml_str):
    tree = etree.fromstring(xml_str, parser=parser)
    if tree.docinfo.encoding == 'utf-8':
        # already in correct encoding, abort
        return xml_str
    decoded_str = xml_str.decode(tree.docinfo.encoding)
    utf8_encoded_str = decoded_str.encode('utf-8')
    tree = etree.fromstring(utf8_encoded_str)
    tree.docinfo.encoding = 'utf-8'
    return etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8', standalone="yes")


data = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Windows-1255'?><rss version="2.0"><channel ><title ><![CDATA[ynet - חדשות]]></title></channel></rss>'''
print(convert_xml_to_utf8(data))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161518/discussion-on-question-by-rubmz-parse-xml-with-encoding-other-than-utf-8).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data` is a unicode `str`. The error is saying that such a thing which also contains an `encoding="..."` declaration is not supported, because a `str` is supposedly already decoded from its encoding and hence it's ambiguous/nonsensical that it would also contain an encoding declaration. It's telling you to use a `bytes` instead, e.g. `data = b'<...>'`. Presumably you should be opening a file in binary mode, read the data from there and let `etree` handle the `encoding="..."`, instead of using string literals in your code, which complicates the encoding situation even further.

It's as simple as:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

#        open in binary mode ↓
with open('/tmp/test.xml', 'rb') as f:
    e = ElementTree.fromstring(f.read())
```

Et voilà, `e` contains your parsed file with the encoding having been (presumably) correctly interpreted by `etree` based on the file's internal `encoding="..."` header.

`ElementTree` in fact has a shortcut method for this:

```
e = ElementTree.parse('/tmp/test.xml')
```

Comment: So if I have a byte array which I fetched from the network (rss/html) with non-ascii bytes in it the function will handle them?

Comment: Yes. If you feed `bytes` (not `str`) to the parser, it will parse the XML encoding declaration and decode the `bytes` to `str` based on that. In the above example `f.read()` produces the `bytes`, but that value can come from anywhere.