# How can you convert a XML ISO-8859-1 TO UTF-8 using PYTHON 3.7.7

Tags: python, xml, unicode, utf-8, iso-8859-1

hi I have been searching a lot about this subject using Python without a success. I have a file that I download from the web and its named import.xml and it starts with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<articulos><item>
```

I would like to convert it to UTF-8, any idea of where I should start??

Answer (score 1):

Getting together `xml.etree.ElementTree` — [The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) with StackOverflow

- [deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885524/3439404) to *Parse XML in Python with encoding other than utf-8* and
- [Tomalak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56683426/3439404) to *xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'write'*

Script:

```
myFileIn = 'ISO_8859_1.xml'
myFileOu = 'utf_8.xml'

from xml.etree import ElementTree

#  open in binary mode ↓
with open( myFileIn, 'rb') as f:
    root = ElementTree.fromstring( f.read())

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree( root)
tree.write( myFileOu, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Tested on the following `myFileIn` file ([data from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<articulos>
  <item>
    <table>"upper"</table>
    <A_> ~A0 ¡~A1 ¢~A2 £~A3 ¤~A4 ¥~A5 ¦~A6 §~A7 ¨~A8 ©~A9 ª~AA «~AB ¬~AC  ~AD ®~AE ¯~AF</A_>
    <B_>°~B0 ±~B1 ²~B2 ³~B3 ´~B4 µ~B5 ¶~B6 ·~B7 ¸~B8 ¹~B9 º~BA »~BB ¼~BC ½~BD ¾~BE ¿~BF</B_>
    <C_>À~C0 Á~C1 Â~C2 Ã~C3 Ä~C4 Å~C5 Æ~C6 Ç~C7 È~C8 É~C9 Ê~CA Ë~CB Ì~CC Í~CD Î~CE Ï~CF</C_>
    <D_>Ð~D0 Ñ~D1 Ò~D2 Ó~D3 Ô~D4 Õ~D5 Ö~D6 ×~D7 Ø~D8 Ù~D9 Ú~DA Û~DB Ü~DC Ý~DD Þ~DE ß~DF</D_>
    <E_>à~E0 á~E1 â~E2 ã~E3 ä~E4 å~E5 æ~E6 ç~E7 è~E8 é~E9 ê~EA ë~EB ì~EC í~ED î~EE ï~EF</E_>
    <F_>ð~F0 ñ~F1 ò~F2 ó~F3 ô~F4 õ~F5 ö~F6 ÷~F7 ø~F8 ù~F9 ú~FA û~FB ü~FC ý~FD þ~FE ÿ~FF</F_>
  </item>
</articulos>
```

Comment: Thank you JosefZ, this code does change the header to: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<articulos><item><node1></node1><node2></node2></item></articulos>  but I now see some weird characters within the converted file. I would like to have them encoded to UTF8 using your code.

Comment: @ingalcala The output file `myFileOu` _is_ saved using UTF-8 encoding. What do you mean by _weird characters_? For instance, UTF-8 byte sequence of the `¡` _Inverted Exclamation Mark_ (`U+00A1`) is `0xC2`,`0xA1`. This byte sequence _appears_ as `Â¡` if interpreted as  characters in _ISO-8859-1_, or as `┬í` if interpreted as  characters in _cp850_ etc… Typical [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)…

Answer (score 0):

I would additionally add decoding / encoding for preserving special characters:

```
from lxml import etree

source = "input.xml"

with open(source, 'rb') as source:
    parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding = "iso-8859-1")
    root = etree.parse(source, parser)
      
string = etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration = True, encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True).decode('utf8').encode('iso-8859-1')

with open('output.xml', 'wb') as target:
    target.write(string)
```